# How to report Xorg restarts?

Tags: xorg, nvidia

Lately I've been having problems with the X server restarting when I'm enabling/disabling Twinview or running low on available memory.

How would I go about reporting such an incident after it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to report a crashing Xorg would be to report a bug on Launchpad, using the `ubuntu-bug` utility.

Instructions for doing this are available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). Good luck!